# System.out.println - Is this method chaining in Java?

Tags: java, static-methods, method-chaining

I am wondering about the the following piece of Java code:

"System.out.println". I am right about this:

"System" is a static class. ".out" is a method of class "System". This is the bit I am slighty confused about ".println"-- what class / object is this a method of?

Also, is this concept known as "method chaining"?

Thanks

GF

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not method chaining. You're right about [`System`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) being a class (just a regular class, not "static" - only inner classes can be static), but [`out`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a static field of the class (of the type [java.io.PrintStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)), and only [`println()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()) is a method of `PrintStream`.

This is an example of method chaining:

```
String s = "Long String ".toUpperCase().substring(4).trim()
```

Answer (score 3):

The class [System](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) has a member variable 'out', of type PrintStream. It's not a method.

Class [PrintStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) has a method println(String).

So no, not method chaining.

Method chaining, as far as I know, is just returning **this** where you might return void, allowing for multiple invocations of methods in a single statement and perhaps a more natural expression of a DSL. You can see it in action in the [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)'s append(String) method

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
  .append("I am a ")
  .append("String")
  .append("Builder");
```

If you're interested in knowing more, Martin Fowler talked about Method Chaining [here](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html).

Comment: "static" is only used for inner classes.

Comment: Yup, I corrected my mistake *just* before you pointed it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`out` is not a method - it is an instance of `PrintStream`, of which `println` is a method.

See http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out